# Copy(): File name is longer than maximum allowed path ... Base64 image

Tags: php, server, copy

I have "drag & drop" image uploader. I am sending an image to my module via ajax as a `"Base64 image"` and then I use `"copy()"` to move my image.

For example: `copy($image_in_b64, $destination);`

It returns

> copy(): File name is longer than the maximum allowed path length on
>   this platform (4096): data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAA
>   ...

Everything works perfect on my local server but I am not able to upload anything on deployed server. How can I fix this? Is this something in server config (what)?

Comment: Base64 encoded file is not a file path.

Comment: Than why it is working on localhost? What is the other way to move this file?

Comment: From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), it seem you need to enable "fopen wrappers" on your server.

Comment: You could also use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) with Ajax and then threat it as a normal file upload in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for comments, I had to encode my image and than I had to upload it.

Solution:

```
$data = //image in base64
list($img_type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents($path, $data);
```